# Create new table with bigrquery

Tags: google-bigquery, tidyverse, dbi, bigrquery

I am trying to create a new table in Bigquery, using `bigrquery` and tables already loaded in `bigquery`.

I know I could do:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(bigrquery)
library(DBI)

project_id <- "my_project"
dataset_id <- "my_dataset"

con <- dbConnect(
  bigrquery::bigquery(),
  project = project_id,
  billing = project_id,
  dataset = dataset_id
)

my_df <- tbl(con, "mytable") %>%
   some_manipulation %>%
   collect()     

bq_table_upload("project.dataset.table_output", my_df)
```

But, I want to avoid downloading and uploading the data.

I could just send a query with `DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "CREATE TABLE AS...")`, but I insist, my intention is to manipulate tables *within bigquery* with `bigrquery` making use of `tidyverse` verbs.

Finally, I have also tried:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(bigrquery)
library(DBI)

project_id <- "my_project"
dataset_id <- "my_dataset"
table_output <- "table_output"

bq_perform_query(
  my_query,
  project = project_id,
  destination_table = bq_table(project = project_id, dataset = dataset_id, table = table_output),
  billing = project_id 
)
```

I don´t get any error when executing, but nothing happens on `bigquery` side, I cannot see my table_output in the dataset.

Is there a way to send the query to `bigquery` and create a new table without downloading, collecting and uploading data? It seems to me a pretty common operation.